# Inno Setup - Hide "Additional shortcuts" label on tasks page

Tags: inno-setup

How can i remove "Additional shortcuts" from installer?

I tried to make `AdditionalIcons=` empty in language files but i think it's bad idea. Is there any way to hide this text from IS Compiler?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script must look like:

```
[Tasks]
Name: desktopicon; Description: "Create a &desktop shortcut"; \
    GroupDescription: "Additional shortcuts:"
```

So just remove the [`GroupDescription` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection&anchor=GroupDescription):

```
[Tasks]
Name: desktopicon; Description: "Create a &desktop shortcut"
```

Comment: Helpful as always. Thanks :)